# PHP searching for table with date but receiving two tables in return

Tags: javascript, php, database, search, html-table

I Have a database in Mysql which i am searching with a date. I can get the relevant results back, however two data tables get returned. One data table has the results of the search, and one table has the data returned from the query. I only want the search to return the results for the search, and not the results from the query.

Below is my code:

```
<div id="searchbar" class="searchbar">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
       <label for="date">Search By Date</label>
    <input type="date" name="search" id="search">  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>


    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
    $searchTerm=$_POST['search']; 

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT question.description AS question, discipline.name AS name, response.responseid AS responseid, response.response AS response, response.student_id AS student_id, response.Date_Time AS Date
            FROM response
            INNER JOIN question ON response.question_id = question.qid
            INNER JOIN discipline ON response.discipline_id = discipline.disciplineid WHERE Date_Time LIKE :searchTerm");
    $stmt->bindValue(':searchTerm','%'.$searchTerm.'%');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=0;

        /*
    The above code is a query which selects attributes according to the search term
    */


    $msg="";
    echo "<table> <tr><th>Discipline</th><th>Question</th><th>Student ID</th><th>Response</th><th>Date & Time</th><th>Answer</th><th>Final Marks</th></tr>";
    while ($response = $stmt->fetch())    /* This is a While loop which iterates each row */
    {
    echo "<tr><td>".$response["name"]."</td><td>".$response["question"]."</td><td>".$response["student_id"]."</td><td>".$response["response"]."</td><td>".$response["Date"]."</td></tr>"; 
        $result++;


    }

    echo "<p>".$msg."</p>";   /* This code displays the postback */
    echo '<div class="result">';
    echo "<p> Your Search Returned ".$result." Result(s)</p>";  /* This code displays the amount of search results returned */
    echo '</div>';
    }  /* This bit of code closes the connection with the database */
    ?>
    </div>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I believe it is something to do with where I am echoing the table. I have shown a screenshot below of what I am seeing:

[image: Please click here to see the screenshot]

Comment: You should post and check your query to see if you get the results when its run.

Comment: @clinomaniac the query is working fine, the results are returned as shown in the screenshot. It's just something to do with echoing the table which causes two tables to get returned

Comment: Have you tried to run the query directly in the database to see what you get? The echo looks fine so I would think that the query returns duplicate data.

Comment: @clinomaniac yes, I have tried it in the database and it works perfectly...

Comment: Shouldn't the amount of results returned be displayed after the table? What is the second part of the table in the screenshot? Did you try to debug the code? Try to print one hard coded row and see if you still get duplicates.

Comment: @clinomaniac the search results should be after the table, but I will sort that once I get the table problem sorted. The second table is the table which displays all the data from the data table, and it's the table which I don't want to display...I have tried changing lots of things so far but couldn't make it any better...

Comment: Try to remove the while loop and just print one row. That way you can check your echo statements and see if they cause the issue. Since the `$result` is also 4, I am inclined to think that the while loop is run 4 times which would point to the query returning 4 rows.

Comment: @clinomaniac I will have a go at that and see how I get along. Thanks